# Generic open of files on netwok drives

Tags: windows

How to open a generic file (Word, Excel, PDF, txt, or ?) from a network drive using Windows?

I had assumed that an html file with the following content would have solved the issue for a Word file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    let q = "\\serverName\PathToFile\NewestFile.docx"
    window.open("ms-word:ofe|u|"q)
</script>
```

Basic idea is to link create a link to the latest file, that then can be refered as a link, that do not change despite the file versions change. url to file works, but is extracted (link inside file is taken), when applying this in a mail in Outlook :-(

Any great ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can describe more accurate what you want to achieve? Opening a file on a network drive using Windows default methods does not require any code at all - just use the network share path (sth. like `\\share\folder\file.docx`). Any application i've seen capable of dealing with links will let the user open a file linked like this - by just clicking on the link. No extra action needed. So i guess you want something different?

Comment: In the specific case I have several (many) files - arranged by date in the same folder. In order not to search for the newest file, I would like to create a link file to the newest file, and only update the reference file. The question goes actually on, how to create such reference file.

Comment: My opinion in that case: I wouldn't want to update this "reference file". If you're going to write and create _"something"_ that would allow to open the most recent file in a directory without having to look in that dir and sort files by date - why not try to get the most recent file in a dir directly by some code-lines? No need to update your reference if something changes, no worries :) -> have a look at this, might help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120801-00/?p=6993